# Drupal show checkboxes/radio buttons value but shows its key

Tags: php, drupal-7

In content types,I have a field sensitivity which field type is List(integer) and widget (checkboxes/radiobuttons). Allowed value list is

```
1|Yes
0|No
```

The main problem is it has 3 fields to choose N/A, Yes, No. But whenever the user selects N/A. When i view the node related with this field. Its value is displayed -1. But, when the user select Yes or No.It is displayed fine in node view also.Any Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

either:

- copy field.tpl.php (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) to your theme and name it field--FIELD-NAME.tpl.php, then display the N/A option in case of a -1 value
- use the THEMENAME_field__FIELD-NAME funtion in template.php (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7), copy the original function and edit it the way you want.
- Display the field in a manual way in an overridden node.tpl.php for your node type, somewhere in your theme

---

the N/A option will be available if the field is not required or when no default value is specified. So to solve your problem: Make the field required, and make either Yes or No the default value.

Comment: @Merijin In my form user can choose yes, no and even they can leave it blank. So that is the problem whenever they select N/A in node view it shows -1

Comment: It's not completely clear now. Do you WANT to have a blank option? Or not? Setting the field as required will get rid of the blank option. As long as you don't set the field required there will be N/A and the machine value for that is -1.

Comment: Yeah exactly machine value for N/A is -1. I just want to change the node view if field contains -1. I want to display as N/A not as -1 which is happening currently.